# Automating fault handling in Oracle SOA in BPEL

Tags: oracle, soa, bpel, fault

I am  looking to implement fault handling automation in **bpel**. The scenario is when there are failed records all these records must be retried at a later point.

Any step by step solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the Fault Management Framework as [in this chapter of the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/dev.1111/e10224/bp_faults.htm#SOASE9904) and set the `ora-retry`policy.

However, you should consider whether [external services are idempotent or you want to do rollbacks](http://waslleysouza.com.br/en/2015/03/managing-idempotence-in-soa-suite/).